# CSS overflow-wrap not wrapping content

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with styling for `min-height` and `width` specified, however I cannot get the content inside of the`<div>` to wrap correctly, even with `overflow-wrap: break-word` set. The relevant parts of my code are listed below:

CSS:

```
.card {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 4;
  border: #000 3px solid;
  margin: 4px 4px 10px 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvettica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-wrap: auto;
}

.card > p {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: wrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="list-1" class="list">
    <h2>List 1</h2>
    <div class="card">
      This is card 1. Giving it some long content without using another p element to demonstrate
      that the problem exists in the div as well as the paragraph beneath.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      This is card 3
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      This is card 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Did I set some property incorrectly on a parent element that's preventing text in these from breaking properly?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03mbew65/3/) for a full example.

Comment: remove `white-space: nowrap;` from your `.container`

Comment: @cb64 yes - that's actually what caused the problem - between your response and the accepted answer, it makes sense to me now - I had set `white-space: nowrap` to the container so that multiple lists would show side by side and scroll horizontally - I missed entirely that that property was being inherited on all the children, which is what messed up the `card` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems you're missing the CSS rule to control the [wrapping behaviour of white spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). Consider updating your CSS with the `white-space:normal` rule(s) added:

```
.card {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 4;
  border: #000 3px solid;
  margin: 4px 4px 10px 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvettica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-wrap: auto;

  /* Add this */
  white-space:normal; 
}

.card > p {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: wrap;

  /* Add this */
  white-space:normal; 
}
```

Applying the changes above causes the text content of `.card` and `.card > p` to break onto a new line, when a newline character is encountered. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark this as the accepted answer in 5 minutes (who knew you couldn't mark something as the accepted answer immediately.)